Implementing SPI with Rust and QEMU
For learning purposes, I am trying to build my own HAL in Rust for the Atmega328P.
Context
So far, I managed the USART part. I created a code that sends back via USART the data it receives, and transmit the data to the computer using TCP.
I run QEMU using qemu-system-avr -nographic -machine uno -bios target/avr-atmega328p/debug/examples/usart.elf  -serial tcp::5678,server=on,wait=on.
Then, I can receive and send data using telnet.
root@61ac6e9f60e8:~/hal# telnet localhost 5678
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
e
Received: e

Here, we can see that by typing the letter e on the fifth line, the device sends it back over USART (Received: e).
How can I do the same using SPI?
I now want to do the same with SPI. So far, I did not implement SPI with the HAL, but relied on existing HAL to learn the use of QEMU.
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use arduino_hal::prelude::*;
use arduino_hal::spi;
use panic_halt as _;

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

    // set up serial interface for text output
    let mut serial = arduino_hal::default_serial!(dp, pins, 57600);

    // Create SPI interface.
    let (mut spi, _) = arduino_hal::Spi::new(
        dp.SPI,
        pins.d13.into_output(),
        pins.d11.into_output(),
        pins.d12.into_pull_up_input(),
        pins.d10.into_output(),
        spi::Settings::default(),
    );

    loop {
        // Send a byte
        nb::block!(spi.send(0b00001111)).unwrap_infallible();
        // Because MISO is connected to MOSI, the read data should be the same
        let data = nb::block!(spi.read()).unwrap_infallible();

        ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "data: {}\r", data).unwrap_infallible();
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
    }
}

I run it in the same way using QEMU:
root@61ac6e9f60e8:~/hal# qemu-system-avr -nographic -machine uno -bios target/avr-atmega328p/debug/examples/spi2.elf -serial tcp::5678,server=on,wait=on           
QEMU 7.2.13 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) qemu-system-avr: -serial tcp::5678,server=on,wait=on: info: QEMU waiting for connection on: disconnected:tcp:0.0.0.0:5678,server=on

And in another terminal, when running telnet, nothing happens:
root@61ac6e9f60e8:~/hal# telnet localhost 5678
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

I was not able to find any solution online. Specifically, of any way to connect the MISO of the VM to the standard output of my Linux shell. I do not know whether there is something wrong with my SPI code, the QEMU command or my understanding of SPI and QEMU.

I'm pretty sure qemu -serial argument is only for RS232 serial com, which is not related to SPI, which is a bus system.

And qemu avr only supports usart and timers. So if you want to continue with your project, you have to implement first the virtual hardware in qemu.

Which means developping a custom device that would be connected to the guest, and redirect the output to the host stdio?

On the host side of qemu you need to have a SPI to UART hardware to be “connected”.
